# Where can I find default config file for postgres? I borked mine

Tags: postgresql

I borked my Postgres config file and where can I find a new one official?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an empty `postgresql.conf`, then all parameters will be set to their default values.

If you want the configuration file that a new cluster would get, run `initdb`, take `postgresql.conf` from the new cluster and delete the rest.

Comment: A lightweight solution [pgtune](https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/) also can help to generate a good and minimal ```postgresql.conf``` file.